# force run Chrome with flags

Tags: chrome, .desktop

Is there a way to launch (a modern version of) Google Chrome with some flags that are unavailable from `chrome://flags` just from the desktop icon?

As it seems, Google did some heavy lifting preventing that. Sure, you can put the flags in the .desktop file and they are force fed to Chrome when using gtk-launch to call it from a shell, but if you just click the desktop icon, they will be ignored. I even went to far to just remove the default Exec line and have the .desktop file call a shell script basically just opening Google Chrome with the flags like you would do manually from a shell. Yet no success.

It can also be rules out, that this might be some sort of malfunction (in my case in Gnome) as it's no problem e.g. modifying some apps .desktop file to add something like `env QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland` to it. Also, if you where to remove the `%U` from the original Exec statement, it will break Chromes capability to open links from other applications. So changes to .desktop files are being read, Chrome just somehow ignores the flags when it's not opened from shell or with gtk-launch